Do 3rd party expansion cards for Xbox Series S allows me to run games like from internal storage?
I bought an external HDD drive, which I plugged into the USB port on my Xbox Series S. It works fine, but some games can't be run from that storage. This is quite annoying for me. The built-in storage is about ~370GB, so there is enough space only for 2-3 games. When I try to launch some games, get that warning:

To play Xbox Series X|S games, they must be installed to the console's internal storage (the default location) or the Storage Expansion Card (sold separately).

The dedicated Seagate storage expansion card is really expensive but in some internet shops I found cheaper, not original expansion cards, which can be used with Xbox Series S after inserting some SSD storage to that card (AFAIR there are limitations of compatible disk types).
Does it allow me to install games there and run them without problems?

They just don't run at all? What happens?

@TimmyJim They can't be launched, I just get an warning about installation rules. I've updated my question and description of the problem, to make it clearer

I see, I didn't realize the Series X/S have a proprietary-like expansion card slot in addition to using external HDDs.  It seems like "Optimized for Xbox Series X/S" games are the culprits that have to be on either the internal storage or one of these "proprietary-like" expansion cards.  I've read that it looks there are some other options, for example I see Western Digital offers a 1Tb option for $99 as well (currently).  Without making this a shopping question, I would think any officially supported option should work, but can't say for sure (don't see why not though).
